# Itereate, store and visualize JSON structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, data-visualization

I'm trying to visualize data from a JSON structure, retrieved via a REST service. I'm retrieving 3 JSON structure via a REST service, and they are dependent on each other. This means that I am nesting 3 Ajax calls. Each ajax call collects data dependent on the ajax call before. Example:

I retrieve all tasks for an department in a company. Based on data about the tasks i retrieve data about the person who requested it. Finally i retrieve data about who the task was assigned to. My code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://helpdesk.site.com/IT/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ITHelpdeskRequests?$filter=TaskStatusValue%20eq%20%27Not%20Started%27",
        headers: { 'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose', 'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose'},
        success: function(data){ 

            $.each(data.d.results, function(a, data) { 
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://helpdesk.site.com/IT/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ITHelpdeskRequests("+data.RequesterId+")/CreatedBy",
                    headers: { 'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose', 'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose'},
                    success: function(data2){ 

                            $.ajax({
                                    url: "http://helpdesk.site.com/IT/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ITHelpdeskRequests("+data.AssignedToId+")/AssignedTo",
                                    headers: { 'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose', 'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose'},
                                    success: function(data3){ 


                                            $(".inner").prepend('<p>'+data.Request +' <br>Submitted by: '+data2.d.Name+'<br>Assigned to: '+data3.d.Name+' | Due in: '+data.DueInDays+' day(s)</p>');    

                                            for(var i = 0; i < data3.d.Name.length; i++)
                                                {
                                                    var AssignedTo = data3.d.Name[i];
                                                    for(var j = 0; j < AssignedTo.length; j++)
                                                    {
                                                        var version = AssignedTo[j];
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            console.log(version);
                                    }  
                                });

                    }  
                });

            });         
        }  
    });
});
```

I'm getting all the relevant data by running an `$.each` loop to run through the structure. What i want to do is visualize on a graph or heatmap how many tasks have been assigned to person. So i'm trying to store the data in a javascript array, but without luck. I can see that my data is getting displayed just fine if i try to prepend it.

The problem is that by running the `$.each` function i get multiple instances of the same person. I would like to have (as an example) a chart which shows the persons who have assigned tasks and how many tasks.

Any suggestions on how to store and/or visualize it?

EDIT Callback structure:

```
    function getAssignedTo(data3) {

    $(".inner").prepend('<p>' + data.Request + ' <br>Submitted by: ' + data2.d.Name + '<br>Assigned to: ' + data3.d.Name + ' | Due in: ' + data.DueInDays + ' day(s)</p>');

}

function getRequester(data2) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://helpdesk.site.com/IT/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ITHelpdeskRequests(" + data.AssignedToId + ")/AssignedTo",
        headers: {
            'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
            'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
        },
        success: function getAssignedTo(data3)
    });

}

function iterateResults(a, data) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://helpdesk.site.com/IT/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ITHelpdeskRequests(" + data.RequesterId + ")/CreatedBy",
        headers: {
            'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
            'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
        },
        success: function getRequester(data2)
    });

}

function getTasks(data) {
    $.each(data.d.results, function iterateResults(a, data))
}


function getHelpData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://helpdesk.site.com/IT/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ITHelpdeskRequests?$filter=TaskStatusValue%20eq%20%27Not%20Started%27",
        headers: {
            'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
            'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
        },
        success: function getTasks(data)
    });
}
```

Comment: you can use named functions, really

Comment: I'm not sure i follow. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: callback hell. as is.

Comment: you can take a look at this first http://callbackhell.com/, then can you change your question to include a reduced use case, so that we can help you

Comment: I'm trying to break the whole function into separate parts, but i'm not that familiar with this approach. It's not working on the live site, but i'm including it in an edit on the initial post. I hope it helps.